# I'm trying to post an array of obejcts into my mongodb using node.js

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to post an array of objects into my mongodb using my `obj` dummy data, but it just posts an empty array instead

Here's my code

Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const LevelSchema = new Schema({
    item: [Object],
});

const Items = mongoose.model('items', LevelSchema);

module.exports = Items;
```

Post routes

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Items = require('../models/items.modal');

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
  const obj = [
    {
      "name":"name1"
    },
    {
      "name":"name2"
    },
    {
      "name":"name3"
    }

  ]
  const newItems = new Items({obj});

  newItems.save()
    .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

But some how it just returns an empty array when I run it

Posted Data

```
   {
        "_id": "90bacff0cc5c2e3734545f34",
        "item": [],
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema is like this:

```js
const LevelSchema = new Schema({
    item: [Object],
});
```

So you have to insert something like:

```js
{
  item: [{}]
}
```

But you are inserting:

```js
{
  obj: [{}]
}
```

So using `const newItems = new Items({item:obj});` should works.